# i18n Smarty variable into lang()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, internationalization, smarty

I want to use smarty loop with variables from mysql Table on PHP

```
{section name=row loop=$userCoursesList}
<h1> {lang('profile.{$userCoursesList[row].course_name}')} </h1>
{/section}
```

And for an example the output should be:

```
{lang('profile.english}')}
{lang('profile.french}')}
{lang('profile.business}')}
```

But probably I'm not using the right syntax, because if I write only

```
{$userCoursesList[row].course_name}
```

SQL statement is working and gives me (english, french, business)

And if I just write:

```
{lang('profile.english}')}
```

This works too and gives me "English Language Course" from my .php language file

I don't know what is wrong, if somebody can help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work, but you can try:

```
<h1> {lang('profile.'|cat:$userCoursesList[row].course_name)} </h1>
```

Comment: Mate, you make my day happy!!! Thank you very very much. BUt anyway can you explain how this works?

Comment: Glad to have helped you. The cat modifier (http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.cat.tpl) is used to concatenate two strings in smarty, in this case to create the string you want: "profile." plus the contents of $userCoursesList[row].course_name. You can probably obtain the same result using double quotes & backticks, but I find it more confusing and prone to mistakes